# How to link a html5 page to a particular article (<article> tag) of another page ?

Tags: html

```
<!--First page-->
<a href="page2.html#note">Note</a>
```

---

```
<!--page2.html-->
<a name="note">
<article>
<div>
.
.
.
</div>
</article>
</a>
```

---

i have tried putting "note" as id of article tag as well as of main div tag under article tag. Also i have tried wrapping main div tag in anchor tags. Still it displays the whole page2.html on click. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute is not supported in HTML5. To Link to an element with a specified id within a page

Try using this:

```
<!--page2.html-->
<a href="#note">
```

It will show the whole page, but its going to your specific location in that page.

Take a look at this page:

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: I dont want whole page to be displayed. And also I dont want to link to an element within that page, the element is in some other page i.e. page2.html.

Comment: I don't get what do you want to do, you want when you click on 'Note' in first page, you go to the second page and show you just the data you have clicked on?

Comment: Exactly.Just that article which is wrapped by anchor tags.